# Checking if 'Input Field' contains specific letter E or B ... return required page

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, onclick

I am trying to validate the input field  with ID 'p_username', if the string contains a B they should be reidrected to the "student.html" and if an E then "staff.html". My problem comes in that I don't know what the command for .contains is. I found this .value which finds if the box only contains the given letter it works.But generally this will be used for B or E followed by a 7 digit character...so I need the script to check if the string CONTAINS a B or E.

Thanks

```
<script>
function validateUsername() {

    if (p_username.value == "B") {
        location.href = 'student.html';

    } else if (p_username.value == "E") {

        location.href = 'staff.html';
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You want to check if the entered value **contains** some character not for exact value, Use `indexOf` as `if (p_username.value.indexOf("B") > -1) {`

Comment: Only capital letters or lowercase too?

Comment: Please tell me that this isn't considered a security measure, and is just a convenience for the users?

Comment: This is just a prototype and no it isn't a serious security measure. I have a 10 month project, 3rd month in just testing the waters. Just using it as an example for a presentation.

Comment: Thank you @Tushar works perfectly, nice and simple. I had this in before it was the -1 I didn't have. Nice and simple for a prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Thanks to Tushar for the solve, nice and simple, had the .indexOf but didn't have the > -1 which was the solve. Just needed for a prototype. Thanks

```
<script>
function validateUsername() {

if (p_username.value == "")
{
    alert("Please do not leave the input fields blank!");

} else if (p_username.value.indexOf("B") > -1) 
{
    location.href='student.html';

} else if (p_username.value.indexOf("E") > -1) {

    location.href='staff.html'; 
  }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
if(p_username.value.toLowerCase().indexOf("b")>-1){
  // username contains b
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `String.indexOf()`:

```
var val = p_username.value;
if(0 === val.indexOf("B")) {
  //
} else if(0 === val.indexOf("E")) {
  //
} else {
  //
}
```

`String.indexOf()` returns fist occurrence index `0` to `n - 1`, `-1` if not found.

You may also try `ReqExp.test()`, as per your comment:

> B or E followed by a 7 digit character

```
var val = p_username.value;
if(/^B\d{7}$/.test(val)) {
  //
} else if(/^E\d{7}$/.test(val)) {
  //
} else {
  //
}
```

Here, `^` and `$` are anchors for `start` and `end` respectively. `\d` for digits `0-9`, `{7}` exact 7 in size.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have to use `indexOf`. Take a look the code below and the example I made for you:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('button').on('click', function(){
        var myValue = $('#myInput').val();
        if(myValue != ''){
            if (myValue.indexOf('B') >= 0) 
            {
                //location.href='student.html';
                alert('contains B');
            } 
            if (myValue.indexOf('E') >= 0 ) {
                alert('contains E');
                //location.href='staff.html'; 
              }
            }
    });

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gon250/z5p02b1h/2/)

I hope it's helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you say B or E will always be first character then you then check as follows,

```
    function validateUsername() 
    {
        if (p_username.value.charAt(0) == "B") 
        {
            location.href = "student.html";
        } else if (p_username.value.charAt(0) == "E") 
        {
            location.href = "staff.html";
        }
    }
```